# Scanf returns condition

Tags: c++, c

I' trying to understand how does `scanf` function really works. Having sample code like below:

```
scanf("%c", &chr);
```

when i press on the input only the `enter` key it immediately returns storing in the `char` variable the `0ah` value but with the code like so:

```
scanf("%s", str);
```

when i press on the input only the `enter` key it waits for a non-whitespace character to enter.

Here are my questions:

1. What is the real condition the scanf returns? What is the (control) char makes it returns?
2. Why doesn't it return only after `enter` key press in the second scenario?

Comment: We have [reference sites](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) for [this kind of information](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf)

Comment: [This `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) might be handy. Note that under the format code table it states that all except a few formats reads and discards empty white-space, which is the source of your "problem".

Comment: It's `0xa`, not `0ah` -- and it's more clearly written as `'\n'`.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the real condition the scanf returns?

scanf returns the number of inputs read.

`scanf(" %c", &chr)` - Here `scanf()` is looking for a character, and since the newline character ('\n') is indeed a character, the program doesn't ask questions, it simply picks up that newline and moves on.

%c does not skip whitespace. The easiest way to make it do so is to place whitespace before the %c  - `scanf(" %c", &chr);`

Just a tip :- Why you should avoid using scanf?
 http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Comment: "scanf returns the number of inputs read" - i know & understand it, but I've asked what is the condition, not what is the returned value. In other worlds what makes the `scanf` stops reading the input and returns?

Comment: @Mulligan It stops reading when it has satisfied all the input format specifications, or it gets an error trying to fill one of them in (e.g. you asked for a number with `%d`, but the input contains something that isn't a number).

Comment: Note that OP's code is `scanf("%c", &chr)`, not `scanf(" %c", &chr)`  (This answer added a space).

Answer (score 1):

1st issue is not about `scanf()` but buffering.

`stdin` often is *line buffered*.  Typically nothing is given to `scanf()` until a `'\n'` is entered.

---

2nd:

`scanf("%c",...)` returns after 1 character is available from (line buffered) `stdin`.  Any 1 character like `'A'`, `'0'`, `' '`, `'\n'`, `'\0'` is read.  Additional characters in `stdin` remain buffered for subsequent reading.  Function returns 1.

`scanf("%s", str)` has 3 stages of operation:

1. It reads and discards 0 or more white-space such as `' '`, `'\t'`, `'\n'`, `'\r'`, and a few others until a non-white-space is found for the next step.  (This applis to all `%` specifiers except `%c %n %[`.)
2. It reads non-white-space characters and saves them into `str`.  This continues until a white-space is read.
3. That white-space is return to `stdin`. (unget) and a null character is appended to `str`.  `str` is now a *string*.  Additional characters in `stdin` remain buffered for subsequent reading. Function returns 1.

There are additional issues if the end-of-file (`stdin` closed) or a rare input error occurs.